Grpc-web not return exactly grpc status always response 2 Incomplete response
I gen code using a command
 protoc -I=./src/proto
--js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:./src/generated
--grpc-web_out=import_style=typescript,mode=grpcweb:./src/generated
$(find ./src/proto -iname "*.proto")

When I sent request that was not valid, Grpc web always response 2 incomplete response , even though my response headers contained the 'grpc-status' and 'grpc-message' fields."
I wonder whether the response Content-Length being equal to zero is the cause of the error.


Hi! Do you mind decoding your "Grpc-Message" header and see what eeror you got there? And also, how are you creating a "not valid" message that you referred to? Is that intentional?
